# Python TCP client not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tcp

I'm having some issues with this python client. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what's wrong.

```
import socket, sys, time, os

host = '155.94.243.10'
port = 80

mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host,port))

message = input('>>>')
while message != 'q':
    mySocket.send(message.encode())
    data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print('Received from server: ' + str(data))
    message = input('>>>')
mySocket.close()
```

I'm using "GET / HTTP/1.1" as the input.

I get no response from the server, I should be getting an error message (I think)

Edit: I used wireshark to confirm I am connecting to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you stop reinventing the wheel and use one of the many python http clients out there. python-requests can be highly recomended

Comment: @e4c5 I'll make sure to take a look at it! I'm also doing this just to learn about TCP though. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Zimm3r No, this is very clearly an HTTP client connecting to an HTTP server, not itself. It sends, the HTTP server reads the input, then sends back a response, which the program reads. It is structured correctly.

Comment: @Zimm3r Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but still got the same results.

Comment: Learn HTTP. Client has to send empty line after all headers. So you have to send `"GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n"`. Now serwer is waiting for new line.

Comment: @furas I tried this but got the same result.

Comment: problem is because it has to be real newlines - but `input()` can get text with  newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client has to send empty line aftera all headers. It inform server that it get all headers and it can send response (or it has to read body if you send `POST`).

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import os

#host = '155.94.243.10'
host = 'stackoverflow.com'
port = 80

mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host,port))

message = input('>>>')

while message != 'q':

    message += '\n\n'
    #message = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n'

    mySocket.send(message.encode())
    data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print('Received from server: ' + str(data))
    message = input('>>>')
mySocket.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** It seems `'155.94.243.10'` needs other headers to get result. Try

```
message = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: 155.94.243.10\n\n'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to add the newlines in with the input.